# Is it possible to set a $_SESSION variable for a specific session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a "control panel" on my page where I can change the admin value in the database for a specific user. I also log the session ID to the database each time they log in, and I was wondering if I am able to change a variable for that specific session ID from the server?

Each time a user logs in the, server checks if the user is an admin by checking the value in the database. It then logs it to `$_SESSION["admin"]`. Is it possible to change this variable from a *different* session when I change their admin value?

Comment: you whant to see if is admin or not when login?is that?

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL no, I want to change their sessions variable when I change their admin value. If they are logged in I want them to lose the admin perks instantly instead of waiting for them to log in and out. The session variable is set when they log in and does not change from there

Comment: I am not sure if PHP can pick up a different session to the one already in use in the same script instance. You could try and test it - session_write_close to close your current admin session, then set the ID of the other session, and call session_start again. You might want to suppress setting of the session cookie before that, otherwise the other session would become _your_ session in your browser. If PHP doesn’t want to play along with that, you could try to manipulate the data in the session storage directly. How to do that would depend on which storage mechanism is used.

Comment: @04FS I'll see what I come up with, thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: Are you using the standard PHP session mechanism? Or something else, perhaps that's storing data in a database? If the latter, that would make it easier to manipulate. To manipulate a standard PHP session, you either need to find the specific file where it's stored, unserialise it, alter it, then serialise it back to the file; or you start the session with the specific id if you know it, change `$_SESSION`, then close the session again.